# Error HTTP 500.19 - Internal Server Error (0x8007000d)

Tags: api, iis, .net-core, runtime-error, publish

I have an aplication API .net core and I I published it. But when I want to run with IIS, ends in error: Error HTTP 500.19 - Internal Server Error (0x8007000d)

This error is because the IIS not recognize the configuration of aspNetCore in the web.config

How can I resolved it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWcUK.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsWjp.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7K5y.png)

Comment: In addition to @LexLi's problem, at minimum you should place your configuration within text when posting a question, not as a screenshot of your editor. Stack Overflow includes tools for formatting text as code so it's readable and even syntax highlighted. This makes it easier for people to read and even copy-and-paste, if necessary, in an attempt to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs because the ApplicationHost.config or Web.config file contains a malformed or unidentified XML element. IIS can't identify the XML elements of the modules that are not installed. For example, IIS URL Rewrite module.

Resolution:

1. Delete the malformed XML element from the ApplicationHost.config or Web.config file.
2. Check the unidentified XML elements, and then install the relevant IIS modules.
3. Install [URL rewriting module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).

Comment: If you spent just a few minutes checking out the screenshots, you wouldn't have given such an answer.

Comment: Thanks! I will do that